# Import CSV column where header includes X?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file with a column header like so:

```
[NPSScore]      On a scale of 0 to 10, how likely would you b...
```

But sometimes the header may look like this:

```
[NPSScore]
```

I need to read this column into an array. My code looks like this:

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file_to_read_for_is_average_nps_score, :col_sep => "\t", :encoding => "BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8", :headers => true) do |column|
  is_average_nps_score_arr << column['[NPSScore]'] 
end
```

However, this will only pick up the latter of the two header options.

How can I write this to pick up any column that includes `NPSScore`?

Comment: Try setting `:headers => false` and skip the first line using `next if $. == 1`, then use numeric indexes to retrieve your fields like `column[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the *first* column that includes the string `'[NPSScore]'` do

```
column.find{|k,_| k.include? '[NPSScore]' }.last
```

instead of

```
column['[NPSScore]']
```

Comment: That will slow processing, especially if there are a lot of columns to search and/or a lot of rows.